# Like `std::set_intersection`, but produces pairs of equal elements

Tags: c++, c++11

I am given two containers that are sorted by some criteria (for example, people sorted by their ID number).

I wish to *find all the elements that are common to both containers*, by the same criteria, and I want access to both elements that are considered equal.

I thought about performing a *merge*, and then manually scanning for equal adjacent elements. But maybe there is a more elegant algorithm?

```
struct Employee
{
    int id;
    int salary;

    Employee(int id, int salary);
};

struct ById 
{
    bool operator()(const Employee& left, const Employee& right) {
        return left.id < right.id;
    }
};

std::vector<Employee> first = { Employee(10, 1000), 
                                Employee(12, 1000), 
                                Employee(31, 10000) }; // Note: sorted by Id
std::vector<Employee> second = { Employee(1, 1500), 
                                 Employee(10, 2000), 
                                 Employee(31, 12000) }; // Note: sorted by Id

// prints the following:
//  [id: 10, salary: 1000], [id: 10, salary: 2000]    // id 10 exists in both containers
//  [id: 31, salary: 10000], [id: 31, salary: 12000]  // id 31 exists in both containers
MySetIntersection( // <--- I WANT TO KNOW HOW TO IMPLEMENT THIS
    begin(first), end(first),
    begin(second), end(second),
    ById(),
    [] (const Person& left, const Person& right) { 
        std::cout << "[" << left << "], [" << right << "]" std::endl; 
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Massa beat me to it while I was testing, but I'll post anyways to show it with the comparison function.

```
template<typename InputIt1, typename InputIt2, typename Compare, typename Func>
void MySetIntersection(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
    InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
    Compare comp, Func func)
{
    while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2) {
        if (comp(*first1, *first2))
            ++first1;
        else if (comp(*first2, *first1))
            ++first2;
        else
            func(*first1++, *first2++);
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the last line be `func(*first1++, *first2++)`?

Comment: Yep, I rearranged things at the last minute at made a bug.

Comment: I see you elaborated on your answer so it's unfortunate that mine was accepted instead. +1 to yours.

Answer (score 3):

What have you tried so far? It seems like a fairly simple algorithm:

```
template<typename ForwardIterator1, typename ForwardIterator2, typename Func>
  void for_each_intersecting(ForwardIterator1 begin1, ForwardIterator1 end1, ForwardIterator2 begin2, ForwardIterator2 end2, Func what) {
      while( (begin1 != end1) && (begin2 != end2) ) {
          if( *begin1 < *begin2 )
            ++begin1;
          else if( *begin2 < *begin1 )
            ++begin2;
          else
            what(*begin1++, *begin2++);
      }
  }
```

([live at coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/805ddd59c6821e9b))

If you really don't want to test, etc the algorithm, you can use an intermetdiate vector and `std::adjacent_find`, like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

struct employee { int id, salary; };

int main() {
    std::vector<employee> v1 { { 1, 1500 }, { 10, 2000 }, { 15, 2500 }, { 16, 1000 } };
    std::vector<employee> v2 { { 10, 1500 }, { 13, 2000 }, { 15, 500 }, { 19, 1300 } };
    std::vector<employee> v3; v3.reserve(v1.size()+v2.size());
    std::merge(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(v3), [](const employee& e1, const employee& e2) { return e1.id < e2.id; });
    for( auto a = v3.begin(), e = v3.end(); (a = std::adjacent_find(a, e, [](const employee& e1, const employee& e2) { return e1.id == e2.id; })) != e; ++a ) {
      std::cout << a->id << ' ' << a->salary << ' ';
      ++a;
      std::cout << a->id << ' ' << a->salary << '\n';
    }
}
```

But beware that this will probably be slower (and occupy more memory) than the original answer...

Or, without the lambdas:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

struct employee {
    int id, salary;
    bool operator<(const employee& e) { return id < e.id; }
    bool operator==(const employee& e) { return id == e.id; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<employee> v1 { { 1, 1500 }, { 10, 2000 }, { 15, 2500 }, { 16, 1000 } };
    std::vector<employee> v2 { { 10, 1500 }, { 13, 2000 }, { 15, 500 }, { 19, 1300 } };
    std::vector<employee> v3; v3.reserve(v1.size()+v2.size());
    std::merge(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(v3));
    for( auto a = v3.begin(), e = v3.end(); (a = std::adjacent_find(a, e)) != e; ++a ) {
      std::cout << a->id << ' ' << a->salary << ' ';
      ++a;
      std::cout << a->id << ' ' << a->salary << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it seems like "manually" implementing a merge. I thought there is something more elegant... like an STL one-liner. But it works, of course :)